# simple C++ project with vcpkg and cmake: can't run through with installed library

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I'm quite new to C++ and its ecosystem, still learning. Recently I'm trying to learn how to install a library and use it in my project.

I'm following the tutorial in the following link: https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/installing-and-using-packages/

I'm ok with the basic usage of `vcpkg` and follow the tutorial install the `sqlite3` library.

And also learned the basis stuff of `cmake`. As the tutorial goes: `The best way to use installed libraries with cmake is via the toolchain file`. So I prepared the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/Develop/test/cpp/test-vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")

project(test)

set(sqlite3_DIR "C:/Develop/test/cpp/test-vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/sqlite3")

find_package(sqlite3 CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main sqlite3)
```

my `CMakeLists.txt` is a little different from the one in the tutorial, I set the `sqlite3_DIR` which is not mentioned in the tutorial (if I didn't add it, the build process will fail.)

And the source file is quite simple as following:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", sqlite3_libversion());
    return 0;
}
```

And I run the build command as the tutorial shows:

```
cmake .. 

cmake --build .
```

these two command run through without errors.

I try to open the `.sln` file generated in the `cmake ..` process with visual studio, and try to build it, got the following error:

```
The application was unable to start correctly(0xc000007b)
```

If I try to the executable file of `main.exe` which I get during the `cmake --build .` process. I will get the same error message window.

Any help or ideas?

Comment: After running main.exe, could you run "echo %errorlevel%"? This would show us if the command is executed successfully or has failed.

Comment: the output of `errorlevel` is: -1073741701

Comment: Ok, I converted the error code from visual studio (0xc000007b) to binary and interpreted it as a two's complement. It lead to the same value. So visual studio and the console start lead to the same error code. The console start just does not tell you about it. So it looks like the sqlite3 library has not been linked correctly. If I understand your code correctly, the idea is to link the sqlite3 library statically and include it in the .exe, right? Or did you want to link dynamically by providing a DLL somewhere in the file system?

Comment: I found another difference between your code and the tutorial. Your code says 
find_package(sqlite3 CONFIG REQUIRED), while the tutorial says find_package(Sqlite3 REQUIRED). You might want to try without the CONFIG keyword.

Comment: One possible explanation could be that the idea is to link the program dynamically against a DLL downloaded by vcpkg. If the DLL cannot be found during runtime, this explains the error. Your need to set sqlite3_DIR explicitly would fit into this explanation. Did you run ".\vcpkg integrate install" as stated in the tutorial?

Comment: first, if I follow the tutorial use `find_package(Sqlite3 REQUIRED)`, then cmake will give this message during the building  process: `Found SQLite3: C:/Develop/test/cpp/test-vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/include (found version "3.29.0")`. And then `cmake --build .` process will fail with error: `Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or d
irectory [C:\Develop\test\cpp\test-sqlite3\build\main.vcxproj] `. My platform is x64. If I follow the tutorial, it can't run through.

Comment: Is the sqlite3.h file present in the directory C:/Develop/test/cpp/test-vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/include? If not, can you look for the file and post the location? The "cmake .." command should generate a Makefile. You can also have a look at the Makefile and look for include directories. These include directories should point to the directory where the sqlite3.h file is.